# AlertDialog disappears after switching activity

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have an android application having an AlertDialog with OK and Cancel buttons. When the dialog shows without pressing the OK or Cancel button, just press Home button of device. The Home screen will show. Now open another application suppose Camera. Take some picture or Video. Now get out from the Camera application. Now open my android application and surprisingly the alertdialog have disappeared. Why?

Comment: Tried to reproduce the situation on a HTC Hero, but i couldn't. My dialog is stil visible even i put my app in the background and run the camera app, and than go back to the app. Which phone are you using? Could you provide us with some code on how you create your dialog ?

Comment: After pushing the app run the camera app and take some picture then press back button to come back. Now go to your app and see the dialog appear or not.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you are creating this AlertDialog onCreate() method.
First, you should read up on the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

And what happens is that when you go to another app, the Activity goes to onPause method, which cleans up a bit.

> Called when the system is about to start resuming a previous activity. This is typically used to commit unsaved changes to persistent data, stop animations and other things that may be consuming CPU, etc. Implementations of this method must be very quick because the next activity will not be resumed until this method returns.

Then because you return to the app, it calls the onResume method, which doesn't create your dialog again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show dialog on startup of application then write this code in

```
onResume()
```

method, it will show dialog every time when user returns to this screen.
Or you can manage its state in

```
onPause()
```